# How to compare two strings in an update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, wildcard

I am looking to compare two string fields in an update statement.  The statement updates the field to 1 if there is a text match and 0 if not.  The problem is that say BLPU_TEXT is '55' and then BLPU_PAO_SAO is 'XX55XXX' it is returning 0.  But I want it to return 1 if there is any match.

```
UPDATE NAG_ANALYSIS.AA3_ALL N
SET N.CARTO_BLPU_BLPU_MATCH = 
(CASE WHEN N.BLPU_TEXT LIKE '%'||N.BLPU_PAO_SAO||'%' 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Many thanks for your time

Comment: Please add a tag for which DB engine you are using - this will get you more relevant answers.

Comment: Do you have control over the database? Given that the text you are searching and the text you are searching for are both in the same record, I wonder if CARTO_BLPU_BLPU_MATCH could just be a calculated column?

Comment: Yes I do have control over the database.  I will consider the suggestion about a calculated column.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for '55' in 'XX55XXX', you need to switch the variables in your `WHEN`:

from

```
WHEN N.BLPU_TEXT LIKE '%'||N.BLPU_PAO_SAO||'%'
```

to

```
WHEN N.BLPU_PAO_SAO LIKE '%'||N.BLPU_TEXT||'%'
```

This will turn to `WHEN 'XX55XXX' LIKE '%55%'`.

It works just like in a regular SQL `SELECT [...] WHERE y LIKE z`, where the pattern `z` is searched for in each column `y` value.